# Как выводит число с типом флоат на консоль в Питоне?

Tags: python

Всем привет. Не особо разбираюсь в Питоне. И мне нужна ваша помощь.

```
n = int(input())
sumX = 0
sumY = 0

for i in range(0, n):
    a, b = map(float, input().split())
    sumX += a
    sumY += b

print(f"{sumX / n:.15g} {sumY / n:.15g}")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выводить число в виде 70.0 ??
Не могу понять как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

в строке форматирование :15f означает сколько знаков после запятой,
а у вас 15g это относиться к числу с плавающей точкой с экспонентой

```
n = int(input())
sumX = 0
sumY = 0

for i in range(0, n):
    a, b = map(float, input().split())
    sumX += a
    sumY += b

print(f"{sumX / n:.1f} {sumY / n:.1f}")
```

Comment: вышло 70.000000000000000. А мне надо просто 70.0

Comment: поменяй чило 15 на сколько нужно знаков после запятой